# How to suppress only [SWF] traces when debugging Flash applications

Tags: apache-flex, flash, debugging, flexbuilder

I'm working on an Adobe Flex application that loads lots of Flex Modules and other Flash sub-applications and Flash resources.  Each time one successfully loads the flashlog.txt and Flex Console show a trace like "[SWF] filename.swf - [filesize] bytes after decompression".  
Specifically:

[SWF] Main.swf - 1,361,299 bytes after decompression

[SWF] core/Core.swf - 516,390 bytes after decompression

I don't want to disable traces because I am debugging, but these traces are rather noisy.  How can I suppress only the [SWF] loaded traces?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [De MonsterDebugger](http://www.demonsterdebugger.com/) an open source debugger for Adobe Flash, Flex and AIR.

It is perfect for what you are looking for, you can filter outputs, color code etc...
Give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is going to be a way to do this. From what I know, your options are:

1. Remove the traces from actionscript manually
2. set "Omit Traces" in the publish settings
3. Test in Firefox and use Flash Tracer. Flash Tracer has a built in filtering options that you might be able to use to better focus on the relevant traces.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what OS you are on, but for Windows I view the Flash log with [TailXP](http://infiero.com/tailxp/) and it let's me filter out lines based on a string match.

Answer (score 0):

I've been pretty happy with both deMonster's debugger, albeit it's a bit hefty to set up. A little lighter is the XRay admin tool, (http://osflash.org/xray), which still requires some setup. (including classes, special trace statements, etc.)

To be honest, what I usually use is the flash Debug player and Vizzy, which allows you to apply a live filter to the debug messages. Although it doesn't allow you exclude words, prepending a word to your traces could make everything that you don't explicitly trace disappear. For instance, you could filter by [custom], then just find and replace "trace(" with "trace('[custom]',".

Hope that helps, or inspires you.

Answer (score 0):

When Using the Flash Develop plugin called FDtrace, I don't see these.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same annoying issue and added a feature request on adobe bug base; please vote for it: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3761359