# How do you disable the [SWF] and [Unload SWF] debug messages in FlashBuilder?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to suppress only [SWF] traces when debugging Flash applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445347/how-to-suppress-only-swf-traces-when-debugging-flash-applications)

I am getting spammed by the [SWF] and [Unload SWF] messages while debugging large Flash projects that use a lot of dynamic swf loading.

I cannot figure out how to disable those messages.